# KnockoutJS Hide wrapping HTML if condition is met

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I've created a gridview component and if the user provides a title as a parameter, I want it to be wrapped in a bootstrap panel. I don't really want to duplicate my markup so I tried to utilise containerless control syntax to prevent the panel HTML from being added to the DOM.

Here is my attempt:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.title-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" data-bind="text: $root.title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
<!-- /ko -->
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
                <th data-bind="text: headerText"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsOnCurrentPage">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
                <td data-bind="html: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText]"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <nav data-bind="visible: maxPageIndex() > 0">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li data-bind="click: previousPage">
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- ko foreach: ko.utils.range(0, maxPageIndex) -->
                <li data-bind="css: { active: $data == $parent.currentPageIndex }, click: function(){$parent.updateCurrentPageIndex($data)}">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data + 1"></a>
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <li data-bind="click: nextPage">
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
 <!-- ko if: $root.title -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

However the result isn't correct. If I invert the condition to `ifnot: $parent.title` it hides correctly.

**Result with `if: $parent.title`**
[image: Result]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that knockouts containerless control syntax requires valid HTML syntax to work correctly. So since I didn't close the div tags when I wrapped it, it's throwing a wobbler, understandably.

The solution I've just come up with is using the CSS binding, and removing the `panel` and `panel-default` classes if `typeof $root.title === 'undefined'`

**Solution**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="css:{'panel panel-default': typeof $root.title !== 'undefined'}">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" data-bind="text: $root.title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-bind="css:{'panel-body': typeof $root.title !== 'undefined'}">
```

Not pretty but it's far prettier than duplicating markup.

Comment: You could make it a little bit prettier if you use a computed binding for the css binding, e.g.

cssPanel = ko.computed(function() { return (title) ? "panel panel-default" : "";});

Comment: @Quango that's a good point. I think I was just being lazy, I'll implement that though. Thank you.